# PHP DomXPath - misplaced <html> tag in Entity

Tags: php, html, xpath, html-email, domxpath

I have to write some tests to validate some email html, so I'm using DomXPath to roughly check that dynamic data is correctly displayed in the expected position.

I've built the html using an online visual builder (i.e.: Sendinblue) and checked with another online tool that the generated code is valid/supported for emails, but still getting the error below when loading email body with [`loadHTML()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php).

The error:

```
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseStartTag: misplaced <html> tag in Entity
```

My HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css" emogrify="no">#outlook a { padding:0; } .ExternalClass { width:100%; } .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div { line-height: 100%; } table td { border-collapse: collapse; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; } .editable.image { font-size: 0 !important; line-height: 0 !important; } .nl2go_preheader { display: none !important; mso-hide:all !important; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; visibility: hidden !important; line-height: 0px !important; font-size: 0px !important; } body { width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0; } img { outline:none; text-decoration:none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; } a img { border:none; } table { border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; } th { font-weight: normal; text-align: left; } *[class="gmail-fix"] { display: none !important; } </style>
        <style type="text/css" emogrify="no"> @media (max-width: 600px) { .gmx-killpill { content: ' \03D1';} } </style>
        <style type="text/css" emogrify="no">@media (max-width: 600px) { .gmx-killpill { content: ' \03D1';} .r0-c { box-sizing: border-box !important; text-align: center !important; valign: top !important; width: 320px !important } .r1-o { border-style: solid !important; margin: 0 auto 0 auto !important; width: 320px !important } .r2-i { background-color: #f3f3f3 !important } .r3-c { box-sizing: border-box !important; text-align: center !important; valign: top !important; width: 100% !important } .r4-o { border-style: solid !important; margin: 0 auto 0 auto !important; width: 100% !important } .r5-i { padding-bottom: 20px !important; padding-left: 15px !important; padding-right: 15px !important; padding-top: 20px !important } .r6-c { box-sizing: border-box !important; display: block !important; valign: top !important; width: 100% !important } .r7-o { border-style: solid !important; width: 100% !important } .r8-i { padding-left: 0px !important; padding-right: 0px !important } .r9-i { padding-bottom: 15px !important; padding-top: 15px !important } .r10-c { box-sizing: border-box !important; text-align: right !important; valign: top !important; width: 100% !important } .r11-o { border-style: solid !important; margin: 0 0 0 auto !important; margin-top: 30px !important; width: 100% !important } .r12-i { background-color: #ffffff !important; padding-bottom: 10px !important; padding-left: 10px !important; padding-right: 10px !important; padding-top: 10px !important; text-align: right !important } .r13-o { border-style: solid !important; margin: 0 auto 0 auto !important; margin-bottom: 40px !important; width: 100% !important } .r14-c { box-sizing: border-box !important; text-align: left !important; valign: top !important; width: 100% !important } .r15-o { border-bottom-width: 0px !important; border-left-width: 0px !important; border-right-width: 0px !important; border-style: solid !important; border-top-width: 0px !important; margin: 0 auto 0 0 !important; width: 100% !important } .r16-i { padding-bottom: 10px !important; padding-left: 0px !important; padding-top: 10px !important; text-align: left !important } .r17-o { border-style: solid !important; margin: 0 auto 0 0 !important; width: 100% !important } .r18-o { background-size: cover !important; border-style: solid !important; margin: 0 auto 0 auto !important; width: 100% !important } .r19-i { background-color: #ffffff !important; padding-bottom: 10px !important; padding-left: 10px !important; padding-right: 10px !important; padding-top: 10px !important; text-align: left !important } .r20-o { border-style: solid !important; margin: 0 auto 0 0 !important; margin-bottom: 0px !important; margin-top: 0px !important; width: 100% !important } .r21-i { padding-bottom: 0px !important; padding-top: 15px !important; text-align: left !important } .r22-o { border-style: solid !important; margin: 0 0 0 auto !important; margin-bottom: 0px !important; margin-top: 0px !important; width: 100% !important } .r23-o { border-style: solid !important; margin: 0 0 0 auto !important; width: 100% !important } .r24-i { background-color: #0887c5 !important; padding-bottom: 10px !important; padding-left: 10px !important; padding-right: 10px !important; padding-top: 10px !important; text-align: center !important } body { -webkit-text-size-adjust: none } .nl2go-responsive-hide { display: none } .nl2go-body-table { min-width: unset !important } .mobshow { height: auto !important; overflow: visible !important; max-height: unset !important; visibility: visible !important; border: none !important } .resp-table { display: inline-table !important } .magic-resp { display: table-cell !important } } </style>
        <!--[if !mso]><!-->
        <style type="text/css" emogrify="no"> </style>
        <!--<![endif]-->
        <style type="text/css">p, h1, h2, h3, h4, ol, ul { margin: 0; } a, a:link { color: #0092ff; text-decoration: underline } .nl2go-default-textstyle { color: #3b3f44; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5 } .default-button { border-radius: 4px; color: #ffffff; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.15; text-decoration: none; width: 50% } .default-heading1 { color: #1F2D3D; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 36px } .default-heading2 { color: #1F2D3D; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 32px } .default-heading3 { color: #1F2D3D; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 24px } .default-heading4 { color: #1F2D3D; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 18px } a[x-apple-data-detectors] { color: inherit !important; text-decoration: inherit !important; font-size: inherit !important; font-family: inherit !important; font-weight: inherit !important; line-height: inherit !important; } .no-show-for-you { border: none; display: none; float: none; font-size: 0; height: 0; line-height: 0; max-height: 0; mso-hide: all; overflow: hidden; table-layout: fixed; visibility: hidden; width: 0; } </style>
        <!--[if mso]>
        <xml>
            <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
                <o:AllowPNG/>
                <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
            </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
        </xml>
        <![endif]-->
        <style type="text/css">a:link{color: #0092ff; text-decoration: underline;}</style>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#f3f3f3" text="#3b3f44" link="#0092ff" yahoo="fix" style="background-color: #f3f3f3;">

...
```

Tried to remove the doctype and the error changed to

```
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): error parsing attribute name in Entity, line: 2
```

Not really sure what this is about...

Suppressing the warnings with `@` made the test run but fail, and since I'm looking for specific tag ids with [`getElementById`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) that I know are present, I just outputted the loaded html with [`saveHTML()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) to file, but here's the content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org=
/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html><body><p>=0A=0A    </p>=0A        <meta http-equiv='3D"Conte=' nt-type content='3D"text/html;' charset='3Dutf-8"'>=0A        <meta http-equiv='=3D"X-UA-Compatible"' content='3D"IE=3Dedge"'>=0A        <meta name='3D"format-=' detection content='3D"telephone=3Dno"'>=0A        <meta name='3D"viewport"' co='ntent=3D"width=3Ddevice-width,' initial-scale='3D1.0"'>=0A        <title>=
le&gt;=0A        <style type='3D"text/css"' emogrify='3D"no"'>#outlook a { padding=
:0; } .ExternalClass { width:100%; } .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .Ext=
ernalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div=
 { line-height: 100%; } table td { border-collapse: collapse; mso-line-heig=
ht-rule: exactly; } .editable.image { font-size: 0 !important; line-height:=
 0 !important; } .nl2go_preheader { display: none !important; mso-hide:all =
!important; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; visibility: hidden !important; l=
ine-height: 0px !important; font-size: 0px !important; } body { width:100% =
!important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margi=
n:0; padding:0; } img { outline:none; text-decoration:none; -ms-interpolati=
on-mode: bicubic; } a img { border:none; } table { border-collapse:collapse=
; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; } th { font-weight: normal; t=
ext-align: left; } *[class=3D"gmail-fix"] { display: none !important; } =
tyle>=0A        <style type=3D"text/css" emogrify=3D"no"> @media (max-width=
: 600px) { .gmx-killpill { content: ' \03D1';} } </style>=0A        <style type='3D"text/css"' emogrify='3D"no"'>@media (max-width: 600px) { .gmx-killpill=
 { content: ' \03D1';} .r0-c { box-sizing: border-box !important; text-alig=
n: center !important; valign: top !important; width: 320px !important } .r1=
-o { border-style: solid !important; margin: 0 auto 0 auto !important; widt=
h: 320px !important } .r2-i { background-color: #f3f3f3 !important } .r3-c =
{ box-sizing: border-box !important; text-align: center !important; valign:=
 top !important; width: 100% !important } .r4-o { border-style: solid !impo=
rtant; margin: 0 auto 0 auto !important; width: 100% !important } .r5-i { p=
adding-bottom: 20px !important; padding-left: 15px !important; padding-righ=
t: 15px !important; padding-top: 20px !important } .r6-c { box-sizing: bord=
er-box !important; display: block !important; valign: top !important; width=
: 100% !important } .r7-o { border-style: solid !important; width: 100% !im=
portant } .r8-i { padding-left: 0px !important; padding-right: 0px !importa=
nt } .r9-i { padding-bottom: 15px !important; padding-top: 15px !important =
} .r10-c { box-sizing: border-box !important; text-align: right !important;=
 valign: top !important; width: 100% !important } .r11-o { border-style: so=
lid !important; margin: 0 0 0 auto !important; margin-top: 30px !important;=
 width: 100% !important } .r12-i { background-color: #ffffff !important; pa=
dding-bottom: 10px !important; padding-left: 10px !important; padding-right=
: 10px !important; padding-top: 10px !important; text-align: right !importa=
nt } .r13-o { border-style: solid !important; margin: 0 auto 0 auto !import=
ant; margin-bottom: 40px !important; width: 100% !important } .r14-c { box-=
sizing: border-box !important; text-align: left !important; valign: top !im=
portant; width: 100% !important } .r15-o { border-bottom-width: 0px !import=
ant; border-left-width: 0px !important; border-right-width: 0px !important;=
 border-style: solid !important; border-top-width: 0px !important; margin: =
0 auto 0 0 !important; width: 100% !important } .r16-i { padding-bottom: 10=
px !important; padding-left: 0px !important; padding-top: 10px !important; =
text-align: left !important } .r17-o { border-style: solid !important; marg=
in: 0 auto 0 0 !important; width: 100% !important } .r18-o { background-siz=
e: cover !important; border-style: solid !important; margin: 0 auto 0 auto =
!important; width: 100% !important } .r19-i { background-color: #ffffff !im=
portant; padding-bottom: 10px !important; padding-left: 10px !important; pa=
dding-right: 10px !important; padding-top: 10px !important; text-align: lef=
t !important } .r20-o { border-style: solid !important; margin: 0 auto 0 0 =
!important; margin-bottom: 0px !important; margin-top: 0px !important; widt=
h: 100% !important } .r21-i { padding-bottom: 0px !important; padding-top: =
15px !important; text-align: left !important } .r22-o { border-style: solid=
 !important; margin: 0 0 0 auto !important; margin-bottom: 0px !important; =
margin-top: 0px !important; width: 100% !important } .r23-o { border-style:=
 solid !important; margin: 0 0 0 auto !important; width: 100% !important } =
.r24-i { background-color: #0887c5 !important; padding-bottom: 10px !import=
ant; padding-left: 10px !important; padding-right: 10px !important; padding=
-top: 10px !important; text-align: center !important } body { -webkit-text-=
size-adjust: none } .nl2go-responsive-hide { display: none } .nl2go-body-ta=
ble { min-width: unset !important } .mobshow { height: auto !important; ove=
rflow: visible !important; max-height: unset !important; visibility: visibl=
e !important; border: none !important } .resp-table { display: inline-table=
 !important } .magic-resp { display: table-cell !important } } </style>=0A =
       <!--[if !mso]><!-->=0A        <style type='3D"text/css"' emogrify='3D"n=' o> </style>=0A        <!--<![endif]-->=0A        <style type='3D"text/css"'>=
p, h1, h2, h3, h4, ol, ul { margin: 0; } a, a:link { color: #0092ff; text-d=
ecoration: underline } .nl2go-default-textstyle { color: #3b3f44; font-fami=
ly: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5 } .defaul=
t-button { border-radius: 4px; color: #ffffff; font-family: arial,helvetica=
,sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; line=
-height: 1.15; text-decoration: none; width: 50% } .default-heading1 { colo=
r: #1F2D3D; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 36px } .def=
ault-heading2 { color: #1F2D3D; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; fo=
nt-size: 32px } .default-heading3 { color: #1F2D3D; font-family: arial,helv=
etica,sans-serif; font-size: 24px } .default-heading4 { color: #1F2D3D; fon=
t-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 18px } a[x-apple-data-dete=
ctors] { color: inherit !important; text-decoration: inherit !important; fo=
nt-size: inherit !important; font-family: inherit !important; font-weight: =
inherit !important; line-height: inherit !important; } .no-show-for-you { b=
order: none; display: none; float: none; font-size: 0; height: 0; line-heig=
ht: 0; max-height: 0; mso-hide: all; overflow: hidden; table-layout: fixed;=
 visibility: hidden; width: 0; } </style>=0A        <!--[if mso]>=0A       =
 <xml>=0A            <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>=0A                <o:AllowP=
NG/>=0A                <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>=0A            =
</o:OfficeDocumentSettings>=0A        </xml>=0A        <![endif]-->=0A     =
   <style type='3D"text/css"'>a:link{color: #0092ff; text-decoration: underli=
ne;}</style>=0A    =0A    </title>=0A   =
     <table cellspacing='3D"0"' cellpadding='3D"0"' border='3D"0"' role='3D"presen=' tation class='3D"nl2go-body-table"' width='3D"100%"' style='3D"background-color=' : width:>=0A            <tr>=0A                <td align="3D=" class='3D"r0-c"'>=0A                    <table cellspacing='3D"0"' cel='lpadding=3D"0"' border='3D"0"' role='3D"presentation"' width='3D"600"' class='3D"r1=' style='3D"table-layout:' fixed width:>=0A                       =
 <tr>=0A                            <td valign='3D"top"' class='3D"r2-i"' style='=3D"background-color:'>=0A                                <table w='idth=3D"100%"' cellspacing='3D"0"' cellpadding='3D"0"' border='3D"0"' role='3D"pres=' entation>=0A                                    <tr>=0A                   =
                     <td class='3D"r3-c"' align='3D"center"'>=0A               =
                             <table cellspacing='3D"0"' cellpadding='3D"0"' bor='der=3D"0"' role='3D"presentation"' width='3D"100%"' class='3D"r4-o"' style='3D"tabl=' e-layout: fixed width:>=0A                                         =
       <!-- -->=0A                                                <tr class='=3D"nl2go-responsive-hide"'>=0A                                             =
       <td height='3D"20"' style='3D"font-size:' line-height:>=
=C2=AD</td>=0A                                                </tr>=0A     =
                                           <tr>=0A                         =
                           <td class='3D"r5-i"'>=0A                          =
                              <table width='3D"100%"' cellspacing='3D"0"' cellp='adding=3D"0"' border='3D"0"' role='3D"presentation"'>=0A                        =
                                    <tr>=0A                                =
                                <th width='3D"50%"' valign='3D"top"' class='3D"r=' style='3D"font-weight:' normal>=0A                                    =
                                <table cellspacing='3D"0"' cellpadding='3D"0"' border='3D"0"' role='3D"presentation"' width='3D"100%"' class='3D"r7-o"' style='3D"t=' able-layout: fixed width:>=0A                                      =
                                  <!-- -->=0A                              =
                                          <tr>=0A                          =
                                                  <td valign='3D"top"' class='=3D"r8-i"'>=0A                                                              =
                  <table width='3D"100%"' cellspacing='3D"0"' cellpadding='3D"0"=' border='3D"0"' role='3D"presentation"'>=0A                                    =
                                                <tr>=0A                    =
                                                                    <td cla='ss=3D"r3-c"' align='3D"center"'>=0A                                           =
                                                 <table cellspacing='3D"0"' c='ellpadding=3D"0"' border='3D"0"' role='3D"presentation"' width='3D"300"' class='3D"=' r4-o style='3D"table-layout:' fixed width:>=0A                     =
                                                                           =
<tr class='3D"nl2go-responsive-hide"'>=0A                                    =
                                                                <td height='=3D"15"' style='3D"font-size:' line-height:>=C2=AD</td>=0A       =
                                                                           =
              </tr>=0A                                                     =
                                           <tr>=0A                         =
                                                                           =
<td class='3D"r9-i"' style='3D"font-size:' line-height:> <a href="3D%22=" https: eb.png.webp target='3D"_blank"' style='3D"color:' text-decoration: un='derline;"'> <img src="3D%22https://www.arieteporteblindate.it/wp-content/upload=" s width='3D"300"' border='3D"0"' class='3D""' block width:></a> </td>=0A                        =
                                                                        =
r&gt;=0A                                                                      =
                          </tr><tr class='3D"nl2go-responsive-hide"'>=0A          =
                                                                           =
               <td height='3D"15"' style='3D"font-size:' line-height: x>=C2=AD</td>=0A                                                         =
                                       </tr>=0A                            =
                                                                </table>=0A=
```

As you can see it is weirdly formatted, and there are a lot of `'3D` and `=` here and there that should be not.
Not sure if all of this is related to the warning I've suppressed.

Here's my DOM code:

```php
$email = tests_retrieve_phpmailer_instance()->get_sent(0);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($email->body);
$element = $dom->getElementById('date');
```

Comment: Try loading it as XML instead of HTML

Comment: @NigelRen switching to `loadXML()` resulted in `DOMDocument::loadXML(): AttValue: " or ' expected in Entity, line: 1`

Comment: `libxml` has methods to deal with errors which might be sufficient in this instance to allow your code to run rather than baulk and quit. Perhaps you can add the actual DOMDocument/DOMXPath code too?

Comment: You might try adding `libxml_use_internal_errors( true );` before you call `$dom = new DOMDocument();` and `libxml_clear_errors();` after you have loaded the html.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius done, now the test runs but fails as it doesn't find the element I'm looking for; I know the element is present (I wrote the email template) and the searched id is correct, so I still think there is something related to the way I'm loading the html that somehow alter/change my original html making my test wrong

Comment: Suppressing errors isn't always a good idea - especially not when you are trying to parse a non-well formed xml string with an xml parser. You may need to use something else to generate your html/xml.

Comment: Find out the error is somewhere in the styles at lines 11 and 15, i.e. the second with the media query (`@media`) and the one between the two conditional comments (the one with `p, h1, h2, h3, h4, ol, ul`): removing these two make the tests run correctly

Comment: https://pastebin.com/seW3hE8B here is the formatted content of the first style